# Couch DB cluster immediate read not available

Tags: database, couchdb, distributed-system

I have set up a couch DB cluster of 3 nodes. Immediate reads from views are not available after write as couch DB is eventual consistent.
Could any help here,how to get data immediately after write (need of application)? Any work around or how to deal with these scenarios?

Comment: Is this CouchDB or Couchbase? You've tagged both, but they are not the same thing.

Comment: https://twitter.com/pulkitanchalia/status/963039217944276992

Comment: Couch DB version 2.1

Answer (score 0):

You’re asking CouchDB to do something it was not designed to do.

Comment: There should be a some way working with cluster (distributed db) for immediate read. May be couchdb does not provide any solution but some other way should be there (may be a cache?)

Comment: As per the CAP theorem, you have to pick one or the other, consistency over availability and CouchDB chooses availability. You need a database that chooses consistency: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem